# Django - how to delete a user/profile with a delete button

Tags: python, django, profile

Hey I have a delete button on my profile page that needs a function

views.py

```
def list_all(request):
context = {
    'users': User.objects.all
}
return render(request, 'users/list_all.html', context)
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def delete_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.delete(user=instance)
```

models.py

```
    def __delete__(self, instance):
    super().delete()
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
```

list_all.html

```
{% extends "myfarm/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
            {% for user in user %}
            <p>Username: {{ user.username }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Ive created an update button that works gives a message whenever I press the "update" button.
[image]

What do I need to add in order to delete the user from the data base ?